# I'm building my site with elementor but there seems to be an issue with only my home page

Tags: wordpress, hosting, elementor

I'm building my site with Elementor. So recently I saw something called containers & flexboxes & I saw that the feature can be enabled from Elementor settings>features. So I did it, & got a lot more resources to build & create dynamic pages with the flexbox, containers & etc.. but I've constantly encountered loading problems, server 500 error, lags, AW' SNAP Memory Errors, specifically for my home page & not any other Page, all other pages are working absolutely fine.

I've contacted my hosting support, saw videos, articles, disabled plugins, re activated them, increased PHP limit, did whatever I can to resolve the issue, but I still can't.

Below are some screenshots of the problem & the Elementor settings.

AW SNAP Message:

[image: AW SNAP Message]

Server 500 error:

[image: Server 500 error]

Comment: The first screenshot looks like a browser crash, due to running out of RAM. How much memory do you have on that computer?